# What is this `[unowned self] in` Swift code doing?

Tags: swift

I came across this Swift code that I don't understand. What is the navigationCallback being assigned to? What is `[unowned self]`? I think I would understand this better if I could see the equivalent example in Objective-C.

```
navigationCallback = { [unowned self] in
    previousNavigationCallback?()
    if self.state != .Canceled {
        callback()
    }
}
```

Comment: Weak versus Strong references to self inside a closure. Have you read the Official documentation? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Comment: It's a so-called capture list, used to specify that `self` will be treated as an `unowned` reference inside that closure. I could expand on that if you needed, but the official docs cover it pretty well

Comment: Did you even google this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the navigationCallback being assigned to?

The stuff in curly braces constitutes an anonymous function. It's like a [block](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch03.html#_blocks) in Objective-C.

> What is `[unowned self]`?

The stuff in square brackets preceding `in` in the anonymous function's capture list. It prevents a retain cycle by bringing `self` into the anonymous function unretained. `unowned` is like an `assign` property policy in Objective-C (non-ARC `weak`). In Objective-C you'd typically do the [weak-strong dance](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#EXstrongWeakDance) in order to do something similar.

Comment: Ah, okay. This is starting to make sense now. So the purpose of `[unowned self] in` is to define a "weak" reference to `self` because `self` is going to be referenced in the anonymous function and it needs to be a "weak" reference because...it's an anonymous function?

Answer (score 3):

That construct is called a "Capture list". As Matt says, it lets the closure/block/anonymous function have an unowned reference to self inside the block. It lets you avoid retain cycles caused by closures that have a strong reference to the object that creates them, when the creating object also has a strong reference to the closure.

This is covered in detail in Apple's Swift iBook. Here's a brief excerpt:

> **Resolving Strong Reference Cycles for Closures** You resolve a strong
>
> reference cycle between a closure and a class instance by
> defining a capture list as part of the closure’s definition. A capture
> list defines the rules to use when capturing one or more reference
> types within the closure’s body. As with strong reference cycles
> between two class instances, you declare each captured reference to be
> a weak or unowned reference rather than a strong reference. The
> appropriate choice of weak or unowned depends on the relationships
> between the different parts of your code.

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2).” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l